# How to use Rangy with PDFjs text layer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf.js, rangy

I'm using [Rangy library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rangy) to select text and apply highlight class on it, the problem is when is select a partial of text the rest become **unselectable**!

My highlight function:

```
  applyHighlight() {
   rangy.init()
   let selection = rangy.getSelection();
   if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
   let highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();
   highlighter.addClassApplier(rangy.createClassApplier('highlight-yellow'));
   highlighter.highlightSelection('highlight-yellow');
   rangy.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}}
```

CSS class

```
 .highlight-yellow {
  margin: -1px !important;
  padding: 1px !important;
  background-color: rgb(252, 238, 124) !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  opacity: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;}
```

A screenshots to describe the issue..

here is the highlighted spans
[image]

and this is what it looks like from the console
[image]

As you can see the "***copies are not made or distributed***" part is becomes unselectable and it goes out from the span scope.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to modify your highlight function to handle partial selections more effectively.

```
applyHighlight() {
    rangy.init();
    let selection = rangy.getSelection();
    if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
        let highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();
        highlighter.addClassApplier(rangy.createClassApplier('highlight-yellow'));

        let ranges = [];

        // Function to recursively traverse the DOM and identify text nodes within the selection
        function traverse(node) {
            if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && selection.containsNode(node, true)) {
                // Create a range for each text node within the selection
                let range = rangy.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(node);
                ranges.push(range);
            } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // Check if the selection partially overlaps with this element
                let range = rangy.createRange();
                range.selectNode(node);
                if (!range.isCollapsed && selection.overlaps(range)) {
                    // Split the selection and recursively traverse child nodes
                    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                        traverse(node.childNodes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Traverse the common ancestor container of the selection
        traverse(selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer);

        // Highlight each range separately
        for (let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
            highlighter.highlightRanges('highlight-yellow', [ranges[i]]);
        }

        rangy.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working right, the selection.rangeCount is equal to 1 no matter how many lines or words i'm highlighting

Comment: Same results, i tried to debug the range count but it still appear as one range
when i log the result:
WrappedRange {nativeRange: Range, commonAncestorContainer: div.textLayer, collapsed: false, endOffset: 40, endContainer: text, …}

Comment: it looks like all of the selected ranges appears as one wrapped range

Comment: Okay, check the code again its edited now, this should work.

Comment: the weird thing about it that it highlights all the span parts like if you highlighted a single word the whole span gets highlighted

Comment: Okay check the code again if it's still not resolved then it's hard to say what's wrong.